# WPF Calendar control has binding warnings

Tags: wpf, binding, calendar

If I start a new WPF Windows Application, and add **JUST** the Calendar control:

```
<Window x:Class="MenuBindingTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <Calendar/>
</Window>
```

And run just this, I get the following binding errors:

```
(x2) System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=DisplayMode; DataItem=null; target element is 'CalendarItem' (Name='PART_CalendarItem'); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')
(x7) System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:(no path); DataItem=null; target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
```

Why is this?

Comment: Well, "just" a calendar is quite pointless... bind its value to a ViewModel.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't closed your `Calendar` object.

You've got:

```
<Calendar>
```

you need:

```
<Calendar />
```

which compiles just fine. This suggests that something else is going on in your system. Are you 100% that this code fails?

Comment: Yeah, mistake on posting on my part.  I updated the question text.

Answer (score 0):

I used Expression Blend to extract the template.  Using the template as a guide, I found this is where the binding errors are occurring:

```
      <ControlTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate.Resources>
          <DataTemplate x:Key="{x:Static CalendarItem.DayTitleTemplateResourceKey}">
            <TextBlock ...
                       Text="{Binding}" 
                       .../>
          </DataTemplate>
        </ControlTemplate.Resources>
      </ControlTemplate>
```

Change it to:

```
            <TextBlock ...
                       Text="{Binding FallbackValue=''}" 
                       .../>
```

And the binding errors go away.

Comment: This works for me now.  However the downside is I now have the whole template extracted (as a copy) into my code.  Not the end of the world, but would like to know if someone knows how to add the *FallbackValue=''* to the binding w/out pulling in the whole template.